# How does an Android app load a keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-2.2-froyo

I need to bring up a few different keyboards: a 'standard' keyboard with Ctrl and Alt keys; maybe a cursor pad; and so on.

I have found the `Keyboard` class, which would let me define a keyboard in an XML resource. I have found that the `KeyboardView` class has a `setKeyboard` method ... and, so far, I have not found any other class that takes a `Keyboard` instance.

How am I supposed to use the `KeyboardView`? I tried adding one to my activity's XML; finding it at runtime with `findViewById`; and then calling `setKeyboard` ... but all this did was mess up my layout and **not** bring up the special keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be very doable, and my initial problems probably had more to do with general Android newbiness (this is my first Android app) and not the KeyboardView. In particular, I'm used to visibility being a simple binary property.

Anyhow:

1. Declare the `KeyboardView` in your XML file with `android:visibility="gone"`.
2. Before you make the view visible, call `setKeyboard()` to attach a keyboard. This is important, as the `KeyboardView` gets its size from the keyboard.
3. To get raw key events, call `KeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener()`.  After refactoring this functionality from a `Dialog` back to my main `View`, I put the `OnKeyboardActionListener` functionality in a stand-alone class, but this is not necessary.
4. I call `keyboardView.setEnabled(true);`. This does not seem to be **necessary**, but I am not sure (yet) under what circumstances it would matter; *perhaps* only if you call `setEnabled(false)`.
5. I call `keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);` - this is especially useful if the user won't be getting visual feedback from an input biox right above the keyboard.
6. Then, with the keyboard all set, call `keyboardView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);`.

To hide the keyboard when appropriate, just call `keyboardView.setVisibility(GONE);`. To change the keyboard (as on a shift key, or a cycle-through-the-symbol-keyboards key, just call `setKeyboard` again. I use a `Map<<Integer, Keyboard>` to implement a lazy-create pattern; a weak reference may be desirable, if the program will run for a long time and the keyboard will not be used much.

Comment: I have created a GitHub repository with a complete working example:
https://github.com/tagadvance/android-keyboard-demo

Answer (score 0):

`Keyboard` and `KeyboardView` are for making alternative input method engines (IME). These are then able to be chosen *by the user*, just as they can install Swype, Graffiti, and other ones from the Android Market.

You, as a developer, can create such an IME, but you cannot force it upon the user.

Comment: Huh. That's annoying - the docs sure don't hint at these being IME classes.  Thanks.

Comment: This turns out to be not true. See <http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/e56c8f8566a1ce7a>.

Comment: @Jon Shemitz: What Ms. Hackborn wrote definitely is more apropos for your question. It is rather interesting that `KeyboardView` works like a normal `View` -- that certainly is not widely publicized, and I definitely was unaware of that capability. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

using the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType) attribute in your editText view will help pick between the different system keyboards (phone, email, etc)  Also the APIDemos application that comes with the SDK has an example of how to implement a forced custom keyboard for your app only.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think `inputType` is quite what I need, but I'll take a look at the APIDemos app.

Comment: OK, I guess it's time to go home ... but I've been looking at the APIDemos source (and searching through it) and I don't see anything about creating a custom keyboard. Could I trouble you for a more detailed pointer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: my mistake sorry for leading you on a goose chase, there is the example http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's some nice source, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I want a native Android keyboard, with my choice of keys - not something that looks and feels more or less like a native keyboard. (In a previous professional life, I saw what happened to Delphi components that looked Just Like Win9x components when XP came along.)