# how can i get to know which application package is invoking the softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-package-managers

friends, I need to develop a keyboard which should have an icon of the app which invokes the softkeyboard.

I found a link which might be useful is here [How does an Android app load a keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938523/how-does-an-android-app-load-a-keyboard)

So how can i get to know which is invoking the keyboard ? or the package name of foreground activity ?
Does anybody have any idea, i appreciate and very grateful to them.

Thank You

Comment: this Question ans can be used as solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620037/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-2nd-top-activity-which-is-in-other-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Question ans can be used as solution [how can i get the package name of 2nd top activity which is in other package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620037/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-2nd-top-activity-which-is-in-other-package)

Get the top activity running is the activity which starting the keyboard, little hacking way but still working :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting `ApplicationInfo` from the context object. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationInfo%28%29) for java doc.

[ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) Super class is [PackageItemInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html) which has a field called [PackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#packageName). This might help you.

You can use the package manager [getApplicationIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29) method to get the Drawable for the application icon by passing the ApplicaiotnInfo object to this method...

Edit1:

You can also use context class [getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29) method to get the name of the application package. Once you have the package name then you can use `PackageManager` [getApplicationIcon(String packageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28java.lang.String%29) method to get the icon.