# how can i get the package name of 2nd top activity which is in other package?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

here in my case, a app invokes a service and the service will inturn starts an activity. My problem here is to get the app package which invokes that service.

Can anybody help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this directly from android source and it works fine :)

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks =
                am.getRecentTasks(3, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
        for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < 3 && (index < 3); ++i) {
            final ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentInfo = recentTasks.get(i);

            Intent intent = new Intent( recentInfo.baseIntent);
            if ( recentInfo.origActivity != null) {
                intent.setComponent( recentInfo.origActivity);
            }

            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
            final ActivityInfo info = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
            final String title = info.loadLabel(pm).toString();

            Log.d("hello","  "+title+" "+info.packageName);
           final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           iv.setImageDrawable(info.loadIcon(pm));
                ++index;
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do not understand it. You are looking for activity, but it seems your code is related to the recent 3 tasks. If the 2nd top activity is in the current task, should we only use recentTasks.get(0)? And why baseIntent is the 2nd top activity?

Comment: There i took recent 3 tasks, for each of them trying to extract info such as title and the icon. I dont remember exactly which one you shuld vget to get second top activity try `recenttasks.get(0)` as well as `recentTasks.get(1)` and test it.

Comment: I only know ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity get the top activity. I don't there is way to get the 2nd top activity. I would apperciate if you give your experience.

Comment: I needed this to integrate with soft keyboard, So always 2nd recent activity will be 2nd top activity in my case :( Have you tried another answer ?

Comment: Are the activities you mentioned in the same single task? how to define the 2nd top activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
          ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(1).topActivity;
          if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
          }
        }
```

It may useful to you to get second top activity.

Comment: use `List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(2);` and `tasks.get(2).topActivity;` instead of  `List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);` because he is looking for second Application which start current top Appliction

Comment: no its not working.. i found ans :) anyway thanks for the ans :)

Comment: @Venkata, have you tried your code? By "am.getRunningTasks(1)", there is only task investigated. Then why is it "tasks.get(1)."?